# Excel - put login times into neat hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this info in an excel spreadsheet
representing the amount of time spent logged in to a computer.

```
logins  time of day    amount of time logged in (h:mm)
------  -----------    -------------------------------
login     03:21     
logout    05:03        1:42
login     05:47 
logout    06:26        0:39
```

And i want to turn it into this ..

```
time of day     amount of time logged in (mins)
-------------   -------------------------------
03:00 - 04:00   39
04:00 - 05:00   60
05:00 - 06:00   16
06:00 - 07:00   26
```

It seems very complicated and I'm getting tied up in knots with excel formulas .. if anyone knows a formula that would be great!

Comment: It is possible to calculate it with both Excel formulas and using VBA it only that is your question.

Comment: Thanks, if you know the formulas to do it .. i'd much prefer to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this, not very elegant may be someone has a shorter method of doing this and will come up after seeing this ugly one, perhaps here is my attempt, exclusively works with `MS365 Version Of Excel`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _H2M, 1440,
     _TFormat, "hh:mm",
     _TimeFrame, WRAPROWS(UNIQUE(B2:B5,,1)*_H2M,2,CEILING(MAX(B2:B5),"1:00")*_H2M),
     _TSequence, TOCOL(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(_TimeFrame)),LAMBDA(_x,_y,
                 LET(_z,INDEX(_TimeFrame,_y,1),_w,INDEX(_TimeFrame,_y,2),
                 VSTACK(_x,SEQUENCE(,_w-_z,_z))))),1)/_H2M,2),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(HOUR(_TSequence))/24,
     HSTACK(TEXT(_Uniq,_TFormat)&" - "&TEXT(_Uniq+1/24,_TFormat),
            TOCOL(BYCOL(LOOKUP(_TSequence,_Uniq)*24=TOROW(_Uniq*24),LAMBDA(_b,SUM(--_b))))))
```

---

Test Case 1:

[image]

---

Test Case 2:

[image]

---

[image]

---

Alternatively posted in `SuperUser` --> [Put Login Times Into Neat Hours](https://superuser.com/a/1836222/1247873)

---